# The sum of squared triangular numbers or the sum of sums of cubes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So I was basically trying to find a different solution for

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^4 = ?$$

and decided to use this sum to derive it
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left[\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right]^2 = ?$$
but now I am currently stucked with the second sum. Is there any way to derive a formula for the sum of squared triangular numbers without using the sum I want to derive?

When the case was to prove
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
by using the sum of triangular numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$
it was possible to find the sum of triangular numbers without the sum of squares via dividing the sum with n and comparing it with the other values of n of the same process (1 , 2 , 3,333... , 5 , 7 , 9,333... etc.)because they had such harmony.
Of course this method usually works on very simple arithmetic progressions so its obviously not a good idea to use it on the problem. What approach would be good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general method to solve this kind of problem. Let
$$
T(n):=\sum_{k=1}^n \left[\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right]^2. \tag{1}
$$
Since the terms of this sum are polynomials in $k$ of degree $4$, it is natural to assume that $T(n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $5$:
$$
T(n)=An^5+Bn^4+Cn^3+Dn^2+En+F. \tag{2}
$$
To determine the coefficients in $(2)$, we compute $T(n+1)-T(n)$ using both expressions and equate the coefficients of equal powers of $n$: from $(1)$, we obtain
$$
T(n+1)-T(n)=\left[\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\right]^2=\frac{1}{4}(n^4+6n^3+13n^2+12n+4); \tag{3}
$$
using $(2)$, on the other hand, we obtain
\begin{align}
T(n+1)-T(n)&=A[(n+1)^5-n^5]+B[(n+1)^4-n^4]+\ldots+E[(n+1)-n] \\
&=5An^4+(10A+4B)n^3+(10A+6B+3C)n^2 \\
&\quad+(5A+4B+3C+2D)n+(A+B+C+D+E). \tag{4}
\end{align}
Following the procedure described above and substituting the values of $A,\ldots,E$ in $(2)$, we obtain
$$
T(n)=\frac{1}{20}n^5+\frac{1}{4}n^4+\frac{5}{12}n^3+\frac{1}{4}n^2+\frac{1}{30}n+F.
\tag{5}
$$
To find $F$, we compute $T(1)$:
$$
T(1)=1=\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{5}{12}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{30}+F
\Rightarrow F=0. \tag{6}
$$
The final result, after some simplification, is
$$
T(n)=\frac{1}{60}n(n+1)(n+2)(3n^2+6n+1). \tag{7}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way
of generating the successive formulas
for the sums of powers
I came up with
a few years ago.
This is obviously not original
but it was found independently
by me.

If
$f_k(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^k$
($f_0(n) = n$)
then

$\begin{array}\\
f_k(n+1) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^k\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+1)^k\\
&=1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (i+1)^k\\
&=1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}i^j\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^j\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{so}\\
(n+1)^k
&=f_{k}(n+1)-f_k(n)\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)-f_k(n)\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{or}\\
kf_{k-1}(n)
&=(n+1)^k-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-2} \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{or}\\
(k+1)f_{k}(n)
&=(n+1)^{k+1}-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j}f_j(n)\\
\\
\text{if }k=1\\
2f_{1}(n)
&=(n+1)^{2}-1-f_0(n)\\
&=n^2+2n+1-1-n\\
&=n^2+n\\
f_1(n)
&=\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}\\
\\
\text{if }k=2\\
3f_{2}(n)
&=(n+1)^{3}-1-f_0(n)-3f_1(n)\\
&=n^3+3n^2+3n+1-1-n-3(n^2+n)/2\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+6n^2+6n+2-2-2n-3(n^2+n)}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{2}\\
f_{2}(n)
&=\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}\\
\\
\text{if }k=3\\
4f_{3}(n)
&=(n+1)^{4}-1-f_0(n)-4f_1(n)-6f_2(n)\\
&=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1-1-n-4\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}-6\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}\\
&=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+3n-2(n^2+n)-(2n^3+3n^2+n)\\
&=n^4+2n^3+n^2\\
&=n^2(n^2+2n+1)\\
&=n^2(n+1)^2\\
f_3(n)
&=\dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}\\
&=\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2\\
\end{array}
$

Using the recurrence,
we can show that
$f_k(n)$
is a polynomial of degree $k+1$
with constant term $0$.

Further investigation
leads to the Bernoulli numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the mind-clarifying responses. I would also like to share my own but probably very weak solution that I found at school.

I also had another solution for the sum of squares by dividing the sum with the nth triangular number and deriving the sum of results' differences then multiplying the formula with the nth triangular number. I thought these types of things wouldnt work on this but when I tried it worked.

defining $T_2(n) = 1+3+6+10+..+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

and defining $T_3(n)$ as $1^2+3^2+6^2+10^2 + ... + \frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4}$

and finding the values of $$\frac{T_3(n)}{T_2(n)}$$ we get:

- $1$
- $2,5$
- $4,6$
- $7,3$
- $10,6$

and take their differences

- $1,5$
- $2,1$
- $2,7$
- $3,3$

we see that the difference between $n$th and $(n-1)$th result is $$\frac{6n+3}{10}$$
meaning that the nth result is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{6k+3}{10}$$
the only result this sum cant find is the first result which is $1$ so we are going to derive the sum then add $1$ to it
first of all $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{6k+3}{10} = \frac{1}{10} \left(6\sum_{k=1}^n k  + \sum_{k=1}^n 3)  \right)$$
therefore $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{6k+3}{10} = \frac{3k^2+3k + 3k}{10} = \frac{3k^2+6k}{10}$$
now we add $1$ to this and it will be the formula for the results

the results = $$\frac{3k^2+6k+1}{10}$$

therefore $$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n k^4 = \left(\frac{3k^2+6k+1}{10}\right) \left(\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{6}\right) - \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^n k^2+2k^3$$

and $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2+2k^3 = \frac{k^4 + 2k^3+ k^2}{2} + \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} = \frac{8k^3+6k^2+3k^4+k}{6}$$
so $$ \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n k^4 = \frac{3k^5+15k^4+25k^3+15k^2+2k}{60} - \frac{8k^3+6k^2+3k^4+k}{24} = \frac{6k^5+15k^4+10k^3 - k}{120}$$
and finally $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^4 = 4\left(\frac{6k^5+15k^4+10k^3 - k}{120}\right) = \frac{6k^5+15k^4+10k^3 - k}{30} = \frac{n(n+1)(6n^3+9n^2+n-1)}{30}$$